# Autohotkey and Visual Studio Intellisense

Tags: autohotkey

I am using AutoHotkey to send a text to Visual Studio. The problem I am facing is that when the text is sent to Visual Studio, IntelliSense gets activated and interrupts with the text.

My questions are:

- How can I disable IntelliSense in Visual Studio before sending the text and then re-enable it once the text is sent?
- Is there any other recommended way of avoiding this issue?

Comment: Try using [WinActivate](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) and [WinWaitActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) before sending the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using clipboard, set your text to `Clipboard` and inside visual studio send a `Paste` command.

```
Clipboard := "Your Text"
Activate Visual Studio
Send, ^v
```

Comment: This method also allows me to send Xml to App.config

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Alt + Space` doesn't *deactivate* IntelliSense, but it toggle the completion mode.

**1. Mode**

Tab *and* Return complete the "sensed" string

**2. Mode**

Only Tab completes the "sensed" string

If you don't use tabs with autohotkey, then you can toggle the IntelliSense Completion Mode with `Ctrl + Alt + Space`. So it will not get interrupted. After your text is sent reactivate it again with `Ctrl + Alt + Space`.